# What does statelessness mean in a RESTfull service

Tags: php, rest, methods, get

I've been reading about REST for a week now, and all I could say about it can be learned in 1 minute, that I can use HTTP requests such as *GET/POST/PUT/DELETE* to manipulate the content of the website

But what is statelessness and the other incomprehensible terms when people describe REST?

Why cant I just add content to the Database throught the `$_GET['']` method like this, `http://localhost/register.php?id=1&username=bob`, here I used the so called `$_GET[]` method - which is I believe different that the *REST(GET/PUT)* method - and inserted info to the database instead of using something that does the same just in a more complicated way to understand

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Stateless) actually sums it up pretty well: `The client–server communication is constrained by no client context being stored on the server between requests. Each request from any client contains all the information necessary to service the request, and session state is held in the client. ` Example: You don't just authenticate yourself once and then do all the API requests you want, you authenticate yourself in each request.. for example by some token in the request or the resource-uri itself.

Answer (score 0):

> what is statelessness

Statelessness is a specific architectural constraint to support scaling, visibility, and reliability.  Fielding describes it in the [third chapter of his dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm#sec_3_4_3).

> Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is kept entirely on the client.
>
> These constraints improve the properties of visibility, reliability, and scalability. Visibility is improved because a monitoring system does not have to look beyond a single request datum in order to determine the full nature of the request. Reliability is improved because it eases the task of recovering from partial failures [133]. Scalability is improved because not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free resources and further simplifies implementation.
>
> The disadvantage of client-stateless-server is that it may decrease network performance by increasing the repetitive data (per-interaction overhead) sent in a series of requests, since that data cannot be left on the server in a shared context.

In short, the fact that HTTP supports this architectural constraint is one of the reasons that it was able to be so successful.

> Why cant I just add content to the Database

You can, of course, modify the *server* state; that is to say, the state of "resources", in response to an HTTP request.  You are somewhat constrained by HTTP in that case (for instance, GET is supposed to have [read-only semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)).

But the server should not be making any assumptions about current client state that cannot be proven in the message currently being processed.

Comment: But if I use the POST method, then I will be doing the same thing as if I were using The Insert into db method, will i not?

Comment: I don't know how to interpret that question.

Comment: The INSERT INTO DB is a CRUD way to insert into the database, if I do this by getting the info through the URL(`$_GET['']` ) I wil have the same kind of "event" going on as If I were to use the POST method by REST

Since with REST I can create content using the POST method,
Does it not make sense at all?